# Strange work of the CAST function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I have simple SQL:

```
SELECT Count(c.[id]) 'Count'
      ,Count(c.[phone_home]) 'phone_home '
      ,CAST(Count(c.[phone_home])*100/Count(c.[id]) as  decimal(18,2)) '%'
      ,Count(c.[phone_other]) 'phone_other '
      ,CAST(Count(c.[phone_other])*100.0/Count(c.[id]) as decimal(18,2) ) '%'
      ,Count(c.[primary_address_state]) 'primary_address_state '
      ,CAST(Count(c.[primary_address_state])*100/Count(c.[id]) as DECIMAL(18,2)) '%'
FROM [sugarcrm_cmsru_dev].[dbo].[contacts] c
```

I noticed that calculation of the percentage is incorrectly. For this expression:

```
CAST(Count(c.[phone_other])*100.0/Count(c.[id]) as decimal(18,2) ) '%'
```

result is 0.24

For this expression:

```
CAST(Count([primary_address_state])*100/Count(c.[id]) as decimal(18,2)) '%'
```

result is 0,00

But the expressions are identical to each other. What's wrong?

Comment: Null values in `primary_address_state`?

Comment: This is because you doing integer division. All you need to do is change this to "*100.0"

Comment: in the second you are dividing 2 integers. For some dark reason microsoft has decided that in this case the result will be truncated to an integer

Comment: @GuidoG actually it is because by default any arithmetic function will return the datatype with the highest precedence of the arguments. It would be really awful if they just decided to change the datatype implicitly.

Comment: @SeanLange Dividing 2 numbers can result in a value with decimals, so returning the result in a datatype that allows decimals seems logic to me. This might be the default for sql server an c# but not in other languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAST(Count(c.[phone_other])***100.0**/Count(c.[id]) as decimal(18,2) ) '%'

CAST(Count([primary_address_state])***100**/Count(c.[id]) as decimal(18,2)) '%'

Your difference is in **bold**, you need to change the second 100 to 100.0, SQL is interpreting the first as a numeric and therefore gives the answer as a numeric, but the second is interpreted as an integer and therefore the answer is a (rounded) integer